# how much more performant is sphinx than MySQL default fulltext search?

Tags: mysql, sphinx, full-text-search

MySQL's default fulltext search sucks when the data volume is big.

So I'm counting on sphinx to get rid of the trouble.

Is there a benchmark data available that compares these two kinds of searches?

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://sphinxsearch.com/downloads/mysqluc2008-sphinx.ppt) claims 50-100x, up to 1000x, while [this](http://jayant7k.blogspot.com/2006/06/benchmarking-results-of-mysql-lucene.html) has even more drastic results. I've used both on dbs, and in my experience, there really isn't a comparison; you just can't use FULLTEXT for a large database, while sphinx is both fast and accurate.